# JavaScript difference between function prototype vs class prototype

Tags: javascript, class, prototype

Does class have a prototype, if yes how are they different from function prototype or they are similar

Comment: `class` is a syntactic sugar for JavaScript constructors which have prototype!

Answer (score 3):

No, it does not. `class` is (mostly) just syntax sugar for a particular kind of `function` - `class` is a *keyword*, not an object like `Function`.

```js
console.log(Function.prototype);
```

```js
// Does not make sense:
console.log(class.prototype);
```